# Dropzone opens twic file select window?

Tags: dropzone.js

Below is my code !

```
<div class='caja caja-white'>
     <form class='dropzone' name="form_-1_11185"  method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class='fallback'><input id="upload_-1_11185_0" multiple name="upload_-1_11185_0" type="file" /></div>
     </form>
</div>




$("#upload_" + nBloqueContenidoId + "_" + nBloqueContenidoElementoId + "_" + posicion).dropzone({

                url: '/bloques-contenidoTop/data/?type=' + tipo + '&nombre=' + nombre + '&nBloqueContenidoId=' + nBloqueContenidoId + '&nBloqueContenidoElementoId=' + nBloqueContenidoElementoId + '&posicion=' + posicion,
                maxFiles: 10,
                parallelUploads: 10,
                acceptedFiles: acceptedFiles,
                success: function (data, response) {

                    //if (response.id == null)
                    //    response = JSON.parse(response);

                    $.myBloquesContenidoTop.m_getAllItems(nBloqueContenidoId, nBloqueContenidoElementoId, posicion, tipo);
                    $('#nombre' + tipo + '_' + nBloqueContenidoId + "_" + nBloqueContenidoElementoId + "_" + posicion).val("");

                    if (tipo == "Documento") {
                        $('#url' + tipo + '_' + nBloqueContenidoId + "_" + nBloqueContenidoElementoId + "_" + posicion).val("");
                        $('#nuevoEnlaceLista' + nBloqueContenidoId + "_" + nBloqueContenidoElementoId + "_" + posicion).hide();
                        $(".nuevoDoc").hide();
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#url_' + nBloqueContenidoId + "_" + nBloqueContenidoElementoId + "_" + posicion).val("");
                    }

                },
                complete: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }

            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes was resolved this issue. just remove file type or input type=file from code because dropzone default taken type:file .that why it was open twice.